# How do I set a UISegmentedControl back to the default value

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I set a UISegmentedControl back to the default value. It starts out as none being selected and I want to set it back to that after an event happens. I'm sure it's easy, I just can't find how.

Comment: Did you read the docs for `UISegmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex`? It tells you what to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set the [`selectedSegmentIndex`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISegmentedControl/selectedSegmentIndex) to `UISegmentedControlNoSegment`:

```
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment;
```

Comment: It's better to use `UISegmentedControlNoSegment` instead of hardcoding `-1`.